# SQL table INSERT statements?

Tags: mysql

I'm writing SQL statements in a table using notepad from a 1NF spreadsheet and I'm stuck on the INSERT statements. There's customers who have multiple transactions with different amount each time. Do I store these or is it just redundant..?

Here's the INSERT statements from the sql code

```
INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (121, 'BD Hammer', 1) ;  

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (228, 'Makita Power Drill', 2) ;  

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (480, '1 # BD Nails', 4) ;  

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (610, '3M Duct Tape', 6) ;  

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (618, '3M Masking Tape', 6) ;  

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (380, 'Acme Yard Stick', 3) ;

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (535, 'Schlage Door Knob', 5) ;

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (121, 'BD Hammer', 1) ;      

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (123, 'Acme Pry Bar', 1) ;
```

each order ID has multiple transactions with different prices. Do I only need to list one price or all of them..?

Sorry, I would post an image but I don't have the reputations...

Here's the values for the OrderDetail table. (problem is, there's more than one value for productprice in each orderID

```css
CREATE TABLE OrderDetail_mys (
 OrderID NUMBER(3)  NOT NULL,
 ProductID NUMBER(3)  NOT NULL,
 ProductQty NUMBER(4)  NOT NULL,
 ProdcutPrice NUMBER(6,2)  NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, ProductID),
 FOREIGN KEY (OrderID)  REFERENCES Order_mys,
 FOREIGN KEY (Product)  REFERENCES ProductID_mys
 ) ;
```

Comment: Does the table have a primary key (unique id) column? If so, is one of the values in your statements supposed to be it?

Comment: Add the schema (part) where you are inserting in just so it becomes more clear what your question actually is

Comment: All the tables have a primary key's and some have foreign keys. Just don't know since some of these have multiple transactions and prices...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your situation completely, so I can't say what to store and what not to store in the database.

Anyway, from what I can tell, it looks like you're missing the declaration of your column names (right after 'Product_mys') ..

Your insert statements should look like this

```
INSERT INTO Product_mys (FirstName, LastName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Ron','Burgandy','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','Norway');
```

p.s. don't be scared to search out some documentation -http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp